# Enable Radio Button Checked On Load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to ensure the "Email" radio button is checked on load rather than the phone.

For some reason the "Phone" radio button is checked onload yet both inputs are showing, I don't quite understand that.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3LX5/4/)

Here is my jQuery

```
var ebuForm = {

        init : function() {
            ebuForm.showInput();
        },

        showInput : function(e) {

            var radioInput = $("input[type='radio']"),
                emailRadio = $("input[value='email']");

            radioInput.prop('checked', true);

            radioInput.change(function(){

                var emailInput = $('.email-input'),
                    phoneInput = $('.phone-input');

                if($(this).val()=="email") {
                    emailInput.show();
                    phoneInput.hide();
                    console.log('Email Enabled');
                } else {
                    emailInput.hide();
                    phoneInput.show();
                    console.log('Phone Enabled');
                }

            });

        }

};
$(function() {
    ebuForm.init();
});
```

Comment: why do this with JS at all. html radio input elements have the selected="selected" attribute for this purpose. see http://jsfiddle.net/Z3LX5/6/

Comment: ^^^ shouldn't it be `checked="checked"`, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @haxxxton So true! I tried adding checked="checked" and it didn't work? No idea why :-(

Comment: @imbondbaby you are entirely correct sir, my jsfiddle has checked.. so was just a comment brain fart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/2F88K/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/775X2/

- Order of the change event
- triggering the cahnge event will do the trick.

If I may recommend: Try keeping your change event outside. see this `radioInput.prop('checked', true).trigger("change");`

The use of `radioInput.prop('checked', true)` is kind of interesting which I wont encourage. `:)` think that radio buttons are `either / or` i.e. one of the 2 will be selected at one point.

Hope rest fits your need. `:)`

**Code**

```
var ebuForm = {

        init : function() {
            ebuForm.showInput();
        },

        showInput : function(e) {

            var radioInput = $("input[type='radio']"),
                emailRadio = $("input[value='email']");

            radioInput.change(function(){

                var emailInput = $('.email-input'),
                    phoneInput = $('.phone-input');

                if($(this).val() =="email") {
                    emailInput.show();
                    phoneInput.hide();
                    console.log('Email Enabled');
                } else {
                    emailInput.hide();
                    phoneInput.show();
                    console.log('Phone Enabled');
                }

            });
            radioInput.prop('checked', true).trigger("change");
        }

};
$(function() {
    ebuForm.init();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the Phone option was selected onload. I need the Email option - Thank you for your answer!

Comment: The update to this answer completes the requirement of the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this...

**Solution #1: (HTML)**

You could use `checked="checked"`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3LX5/10/)**

**Solution #2: (JQuery)**

```
var email = $("#email");

email.prop('checked', true);
```

And to hide the phone input on page load, you can `trigger` the `change` event:

```
email.prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3LX5/14/)**

Comment: Your HTML Demo worked but not the jQuery. Sure the Email option was selected but didn't hide the phone input. Thank you for the info!

Comment: You have to remove `radioInput.prop('checked', true);` for that to work since both have the same name.

Comment: You will have to use `email.prop('checked', true).trigger('change');` in the function to fix this issue :)

Comment: Updated the answer for you!

Answer (score 1):

First `input[value='email']` is not such a good selector -- use `#email` instead. The reason the phone radio button is checked is because you are checking it with the code:

```
        radioInput.prop('checked', true);
```

Your probably wanted to write:

```
       emailRadio.prop('checked', true);
```

And remember you cannot check both `phone` and `email`! They both have the same `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3LX5/12/)

The key here is `$('#email').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');`